# How can I post message in Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

This project run with a `web server`. When user click button, it should post the message inside of `EditText`. I use `Retrofit2` for it. The program has stoped when I click button.

```
ApiInterface.java

@POST("api/EmergencyNotification/SendNotification")
Call<SendMessageModel>postMessage(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                              //  @Field(("PhotoRequest")) String photoRequest,
                              //  @Field(("Location")) String location,
                                @Field(("MessageBody")) String messageBody);
                                //  @Field(("AnswerValue")) String answerValue);
```

In the button `OnClick` this function runs:

```
protected void postMessage(){
    startProgress();
    String authorization = SessionHelper.getCustomerTokenWithBearer();
   // Loc = lattitude + longitude;
    Call<SendMessageModel> call = ApiService.apiInterface.postMessage(authorization,
            mesaj.getText().toString().trim());

   call.enqueue(new Callback<SendMessageModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SendMessageModel> call, Response<SendMessageModel> response) {
            stopProgress();

            if (response.isSuccessful()){

                if (response.body() != null){
                    DialogHelper.showDialogWithOneButton("",response.body().getData());
               }
            }
            else {
                ApiErrorUtils.parseError(response);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SendMessageModel> call, Throwable t) {

            stopProgress();
            DialogHelper.showFailedDialog();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: your API is form-data or JSON request?

Comment: It's  form-data.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I solved it now. My api url was wrong and I added new `@Multipart` and `@Part` instead of `@Field`.

```
@POST("api/EmergencyNotification/SendMessage")
  Call<SendMessageModel>postMessage(@Header("Authorization") String token,

                                    @Part(("MessageBody")) String messageBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `@FormUrlEncoded` attribute since you are using field attribute instead of body

```
@POST("api/EmergencyNotification/SendNotification")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<SendMessageModel>postMessage(@Header("Authorization") String token,
...
```

Comment: It don't work. That's form-data in postman. not form-urlencoded.

Comment: then don't use field attribute, use `@Body("MessageBody") String messageBody`

Comment: ok I will try. Normally there location and photo that I must send. So I use fields for this reason. I am trying only send message now firstly. So I make them comment line.

Comment: When I use @Body. There is error in MessageBody, it say cannot find method 'value'.